# How to broadcast an Event in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

Given a JavaFX Application with multiple presenters and views organized in a hierarchy. How can I broadcast events from a parent presenter down to a child presenter/view?

My architecture looks as following: I have a MainPresenter wich is on top of the hierarchy

```
public class MainPresenter {

    @FXML private TreeView<String> navigation;
    @FXML private AnchorPane       contentView;
    @Autowired private MainView    mainView;
    @Autowired private DetailView  detailView;

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {

        // register a handler for selection of treeview items
        navigation.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
            new ChangeListener<TreeItem<String>>() {
                // ...          
                contentView.getChildren().clear();
                contentView.getChildren().add(detailView);
                contentView.fireEvent(new ResourceEvent(ResourceEvent.SELECTED, model));
                // ...
            }
        );
    }
}
```

There is also a presenter for the detail view of the selected item:

```
public class DetailPresenter {

    @Autowired private DetailView       view;

    @PostConstruct
    public void postInit() {
        // is being executed
        view.getView().addEventHandler(ResourceEvent.SELECTED, (event) -> {
            // not being invoked
        });
    }
}
```

What I want to achive is that whenever a item is selected in the TreeView the DetailView for this item should be added to the scene graph (works) and the DetailPresenter should be notified to load the resource from a backend service.
One solution to this would be to simply autowire the `DetailPresenter` in the `MainPresenter`, which is not what I want to to. I want to have loose coupling. As I assumed from the Documentation [on Event Handling](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/events.htm) a Event is dispatched down to all nodes in the scene graph and is then bubbling up back to the root of the scene. Since the `EventHandler` in my `DetailPresenter` is not invoked, I figure that the event is not being passed down.

My question would be, how would one achieve this?

Comment: im sure you have solve this right? or?

Comment: In fact I ended up using a external publish/subscribe mechanism. If you use spring for your application have a look at springs application events. I ended up rolling my own EventBus since I didn't need any fancy features.

Answer (score 0):

`MyModel.java`:

```
public class MyModel {
  private StringProperty myString = new SimpleStringProperty();
  public void setMyString(String myString) { this.myString.set(myString); }
  public String getMyString() { return myString.get(); }
  public StringProperty getMyStringProperty() { return myString; }
}
```

Then create an instance of `MyModel` as singleton bean (looks like you're using Spring). And inject your model where it is needed:

```
@Bean
public MyModel myModel() {
  return new MyModel();
}
```

Then inject it and bind to the property:

```
public class MyPresenter {
  @FXML TextField myTextField;
  @Autowired MyModel myModel;

  public void initialize() {
    myTextField.textProperty().bind(myModel.getMyStringProperty());
  }
}
```

If now someone updates the `myString` property the UI `myTextField` will update as well.

You may also register some custom handler on those properties or use twoWayBinding.

So you don't have to use it as UI element, but can also use it as some kind of data-pipeline.